# I have a problems with js jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JS. My code is basically like this. I want to select ul has the same id of class of a button. Apparently on this case, x does not stand for its value. Any ideas?

```
$(function(){
    $('.buttons button').click(function(){
        var x = $(this).attr('class');
        $('ul[id=x]').toggleClass('noshow');
})
})
```

Comment: `$('#' + x).toggleClass('noshow')`

Comment: Can you show the html?

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Got it now. Coding is joyful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.buttons button').click(function(){
        var x = $(this).attr('class');
        $('ul#'+x).toggleClass('noshow');
    });
});
```